# How to parse XML from a variable?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

How do the XML parsing, in a variable with Perl?

I get from my URL-encoded database, proceed with URL decode and I get an XML document.

I need to parse this XML.

I hope I was clear

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag>
   <field type="tag">
      <content>
         <it>Ristoranti e Pizzerie</it>
         <de>Restaurants und Pizzeria</de>
         <en>Restaurants and pizzerias</en>
      </content>
      <valore>TAG14</valore>
   </field>
   <field type="tag">
      <content>
         <it>Bar, Pub ed Enoteche</it>
         <de>Bar, Pub und Enotheken</de>
         <en>Bars, pubs and wine store</en>
      </content>
      <valore>TAG15</valore>
   </field>
</tag>
```

Comment: what you have tried? Please show us what you have tried then only we can help.

Comment: What is the problem? In general you *have* to read the XML data into a variable before you parse it, although some modules allow you to specify a file name or file handle and hide the reading from you. Which module are you using?

Comment: `my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parse ( $xml )`. Of course, without knowing what you actually want to do, that's about the most I can give you.

Comment: @Borodin XML is contained in the variable $ tag.

Comment: @Sobrique i have take the value and the voice it de en of tag in this example the value is <valore>TAG15</valore> and  the voice is <it>Ristoranti e Pizzerie</it>
         <de>Restaurants und Pizzeria</de>
         <en>Restaurants and pizzerias</en>

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Task::Kensho::XML

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what the problem is

The two most popular high-quality XML modules are [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) and [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML). The program below uses *both* of them to parse the same XML data from your question

***Note that you will use only one module or the other; not both as here***

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::Twig;
## OR
use XML::LibXML;

my $tag = <<END_XML;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag>
   <field type="tag">
      <content>
         <it>Ristoranti e Pizzerie</it>
         <de>Restaurants und Pizzeria</de>
         <en>Restaurants and pizzerias</en>
      </content>
      <valore>TAG14</valore>
   </field>
   <field type="tag">
      <content>
         <it>Bar, Pub ed Enoteche</it>
         <de>Bar, Pub und Enotheken</de>
         <en>Bars, pubs and wine store</en>
      </content>
      <valore>TAG15</valore>
   </field>
</tag>
END_XML

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parse($tag);

## OR

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $tag);
```

Comment: Borodin i get this error no element found at line 1, column 0, byte -1 at /usr/lib/perl5/XML/Parser.pm line 187
 at elenco_negozi.pl line 195

Comment: Check the first line - make sure there's no leading whitespace.

Comment: @Sobrique not have a whitespace.

Comment: The code I have shown works fine. Check your own program carefully for differences. If you cannot find the problem then you may open a new question and we will help you with it.

Comment: @Python_96: you have space before **" <**?xml versio"

Comment: @Borodin's code works as described. Your error message suggests that you've got a problem with the very first character of your XML. Which if your post above is correct, has a space just before the XML declaration.

Comment: @Python_96: That error would be the result if your `$tag` variable was empty. You should print the variable and make sure it contains what you think it does.

Comment: @Sobrique: That problem would be indicated by `XML or text declaration not at start of entity` from `XML::Twig` or `XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document` from `XML::LibXML`. Without an XML declaration, leading whitespace isn't an error. My best guess is that `$tag` is an empty string.

Comment: @Borodin 
the declaration of tag:
 $tag = &ParseTxt($tipoAdmin{$idStruttura}{'62'});
       $tag = encode_entities( $tag );
       my $twig = XML::Twig->new;